# How to fix problem “Clickable elements too close together” in Google Search Console

Tags: css, button, google-search, google-search-appliance, google-search-console

I'm currently developing a website and just submitted it to Google SC. After indexing, I got the error "Clickable elements are toot close together". I followed the guide made by Google for Accessible styles, but the error persisted.

The URL is: https://www.myresearchorganization.com

Any tips or fixes?

Answer (score 1):

Usually, it means that elements on your page are too small or overlap each other. Google recommends 48x48px size as a minimum size for clickable elements. On your site, the problem might be in a block with social icons, because elements (Facebook, Twitter, Instagram, and Youtube links) are only 32x21px, and they are located very close to each other which makes them "hard" clickable on mobile devices.